# How to declare a watch on the this object in a factory method in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have a factory class defined which i am instantiating in the controller.

I want to define a method in the factory declaration of the User class which will be notified to when any of its properties are changed .

[image]

Below is the link for the code at code pen

```
app.factory('User', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    function User(userData) {
        User.prototype.Name = userData.nameSample;
        User.prototype.Age = userData.Age;

        $rootScope.$watch(this, function (oldValue, newValue) {

        }, true);
    };

    User.prototype = {
        Name: null,
        Age: null
    }

    return User;
}]);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjWyWP?editors=101

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You should remove your images of code and questions and replace them with code and questions :)

Comment: What is your codepen not doing correctly?

Comment: Sorry the code pen missed a line of code . It is now updated i have added a $rootScope.$watch method in the User class the name property in the User class is bound to a input type text . What i need is every time there is a change to this Name property i want to be able to fire an event to a method in the instance of that User class.